# Scala: I have a union of csv files in RDD how to write the RDD data in to new csv file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a multiple csv files in the directory path, I have to take all the csv files from the directory and I have to union all the csv files and needs to store in RDD. once the unioned data in RDD the same RDD data I have to write back in csv file. I am writing the below code however I am not able to meet the requirement.

Please help me,

```
val rdd = getListOfFilenames()
  .map(spark.sparkContext.textFile(_))
  .foldLeft(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[String])(_ union _)
```

(or)

```
val rdd = List("file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5")
  .map(spark.sparkContext.textFile(_))
  .reduce(_ union _)

rdd.write.option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv(test1.csv")
```

I am getting the below error,

```
write is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
```

Comment: Yeah because write is not a member of RDD[String] its member of Dataframe or Dataset you need to convert them into that and then write

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please help on this

Answer (score 1):

First, load your files as CSVs. You'll be getting back a list of dataframes.

```
val dataframes = List("file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5")
  .map(spark.read.option("header", true).csv(_))
```

Assuming they have the same schema:

```
val combined = dataframes.reduce(_ union _)
```

Finally, write the combined dataframe:

```
combined.write.option("header", true)
  .coalesce(1).csv("output.csv)
```

Comment: Could you please modify the above code to serve the purpose. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Chandra - updated the answer for merging the input as CSVs rather than text files.

Comment: val filesData=List("file1", "file2")

         val dataframes = filesData.map(spark.read.option("header", true).csv(_))

         val combined = dataframes.reduce(_ union _)

         val data = combined.rdd

     val head :Array[String]= data.first()

    val dataRDD = data.filter(_(0) != head(0))

 type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.Row required: Array[String] ... please let me know what's the error in my code here

Comment: @Chandra You get `Rdd[Row]` when you convert a dataframe to rdd. Are you trying to skip the header? If yes, `option("header", "true")` that you specified above does exactly that.